# How can I find router addresses of decentralized exchanges

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange

When I want to find router addresses like pancakeswap router (V2) or uniswap router, I can search them like `pancakeswap router bscscan` in Google or track transactions in bscscan.com to find them. Do you know a simple and fast way to see all router addresses that is possible to track in the BSC or ETH network? (for example a page in coingecko.com)

Answer (score 0):

It seems we can filter transactions by methods on this page https://etherscan.io/advanced-filter?. And we can search them by known methods like `swapExactTokensForTokens`